# How to set the name of the WPF rendering thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'd like to set the name of the "invisible" WPF rendering thread.  In order to do that, is there a way to 1) get access to the thread object for the WPF rendering thread or 2) execute  on the WPF rendering thread that sets the current thread's name?

Comment: The rendering thread is the main thread if that helps.

Comment: What makes you think the main thread of a WPF application is "invisible"? It's exactly the opposite: You have to explicitly use threading to break free from it.

Comment: "All WPF applications start with two threads: one for managing the UI and another background thread for handling rendering and repainting. Rendering and repainting is managed by WPF itself, without any developer intervention." (http://www.gigyonline.com/code/source/wpf.html).  I want to set the name of the thread that handles "rendering and repainting".

Comment: Another reference: "All WPF applications start out with two important threads, one for rendering and one for managing the user interface. The rendering thread is a hidden thread that runs in the background, so the only thread that you ordinarily deal with is the UI thread." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Comment: Why do you need to set the name of this invisible rendering thread?   Even by you own quote it is designed to be used without any developer intervention.  As a developer you can only access a UI object on the thread that created the UI object and that is the main thread.

Comment: I want to set the name of it so I can see what thread it is in the debugger.